# Android Studio Spinner Code

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Please, someone, tell me my mistake in the attached code of spinner. It crashes the application

```
 String arr[] = {"Maths", "Biology"};
 ArrayAdapter a = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);
 Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin1);
 spin.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
 spin.setAdapter(a);
```

Comment: what error message are you getting?

Comment: Is this code inside an activity witch implements the interface Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener? if so, have you implements this interface callback?

Comment: @emecas No error actually it crashes the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast activity for AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener

```
spin.setAdapter(a);
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             //Get position and the related item from here
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                //Another interface callback
            }
        });
```

Comment: This code can be used when your activity not implemented the onItemSelectedListener. If your activity had implemented the AdapterView,onItemSelectedListener your original code would have worked.I put this way since I mostly use this way. You can see in most places we use both these two ways either to listen button clicks or any other View based events